# Reputation change for removed questions

Tags: discussion, support, reputation, deleted-questions

Since I havn't experienced this, I want to ask it beforehand. If a question receives a number of down votes causing the asker to lose reputation, and then is deleted, will the reputation be restored or remain as it is? Same thing goes for up votes too. Sorry if this is already discussed. Couldn't find the post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you delete a question or answer then regardless of upvotes or downvotes your reputation will be reverted back to what it was before. So say for a question if you got 1 upvote (+5 reputation) and then 2 downvotes (-4 reputation) while sitting at -1 votes if you deleted it you'd lose the 1 reputation point you'd gained. Conversely for 5 downvotes (-10 rep) you'd get that back upon deletion.

Something to remember though is that deleted posts still count towards automated question / answer bans. A person that posts a lot of questions or answers that are heavily downvoted can still get banned for that reason. That helps prevent people posting a continous stream of low quality content and then simply deleting it.

The exact rules for question / answer bans aren't made public to prevent gaming the system but from what I gather having a lot of deleted posts weighs heavily into the rules.